# Append Python List of Dictionaries by loops

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 Python List of Dictionaries:

```
[{'index':'1','color':'red'},{'index':'2','color':'blue'},{'index':'3','color':'green'}]
```

&

```
[{'device':'1','name':'x'},{'device':'2','name':'y'},{'device':'3','name':'z'}]
```

How can I Append each dictionary of second list to the first list so as to get an output as:

```
[{'device':'1','name':'x'},{'index':'1','color':'red'},{'index':'2','color':'blue'},{'index':'3','color':'green'}]

[{'device':'2','name':'y'},{'index':'1','color':'red'},{'index':'2','color':'blue'},{'index':'3','color':'green'}]

[{'device':'3','name':'z'},{'index':'1','color':'red'},{'index':'2','color':'blue'},{'index':'3','color':'green'}]
```

Comment: You may want to consider if there is a better structure for what you are trying to achieve - these multilevel nested lists and dictionaries may get difficult to work with.

Comment: Sure, I would look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you wanted to save your result lists, so I printed them out:

```
d1 = [{'index':'1','color':'red'},{'index':'2','color':'blue'},{'index':'3','color':'green'}]   
d2 = [{'device':'1','name':'x'},{'device':'2','name':'y'},{'device':'3','name':'z'}]

for item in d2:
    print ([item] + d1)
```

The output:

> [{'name': 'x', 'device': '1'}, {'index': '1', 'color': 'red'}, {'index': '2', 'color': 'blue'}, {'index': '3', 'color': 'green'}]
>   [{'name': 'y', 'device': '2'}, {'index': '1', 'color': 'red'}, {'index': '2', 'color': 'blue'}, {'index': '3', 'color': 'green'}]
>   [{'name': 'z', 'device': '3'}, {'index': '1', 'color': 'red'}, {'index': '2', 'color': 'blue'}, {'index': '3', 'color': 'green'}]

(Don't be confused by order of items in individual directories as directories are not ordered.)

Comment: [{'name': 'x', 'device': '1,'index': '1', 'color': 'red'}, {'name': 'x','index': '2', 'color': 'blue'}, {'name': 'x','index': '3', 'color': 'green'}]
[{'name': 'y','index': '1', 'color': 'red'}, {'name': 'y','index': '2', 'color': 'blue'}, {'name': 'y','index': '3', 'color': 'green'}]
[{'name': 'z','index': '1', 'color': 'red'}, {'name': 'z','index': '2', 'color': 'blue'}, {'name': 'z','index': '3', 'color': 'green'}]     is this possible?

Comment: In Python everything is possible. Please formulate it as a new question and I will answer you. (Then please write comment about your new question **here** so as I will be notified.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848193/python-list-of-dictionaries-by-loops

Comment: I formulated it as a new question, with the link I gave above.

Comment: I answered it already - I have first to request for un-duplicate it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the following code answers your question:

```
indexes = [
    {'index':'1','color':'red'},
    {'index':'2','color':'blue'},
    {'index':'3','color':'green'}
]
devices = [
    {'device':'1','name':'x'},
    {'device':'2','name':'y'},
    {'device':'3','name':'z'}
]
new_lists = [[device] for device in devices]
for new_list in new_lists:
    new_list.extend(indexes)
```