# Python List of Dictionaries by Loops

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 python list of dictionaries:

```
[
    {'index':'1','color':'red'},
    {'index':'2','color':'blue'},
    {'index':'3','color':'green'}
]
```

and

```
[
    {'device':'1','name':'x'},
    {'device':'2','name':'y'},
    {'device':'3','name':'z'}
]
```

How can I append each dictionary from the second list to the first list so as to get an output as:

```
[
    {'device':'1','name':'x','index': '1', 'color': 'red'},
    {'device':'1','name':'x','index': '2', 'color': 'blue'},
    {'device':'1','name': 'x','index': '3', 'color': 'green'}
    {'device':'2','name':'y''index': '1', 'color': 'red'},
    {'device':'2','name':'y','index': '2', 'color': 'blue'},
    {'device':'2','name':'y','index': '3', 'color': 'green'}
    {'device':'3','name':'z','index': '1', 'color': 'red'}, 
    {'device':'3','name':'z','index': '2', 'color': 'blue'}, 
    {'device':'3','name':'z','index': '3', 'color': 'green'}
]
```

Comment: where did the `device` key go on the 2nd and 3rd dicts in the resulting lists?

Comment: why are there a total of 6 dictionaries in the input and 9 in the output? some of the dictionaries looked merged but the device key is only in one of the output dicts?

Comment: Why is the output a "list of lists"?

Comment: In your example output, the first dictionary of the first list is the updated dictionary that you want. However, every other dictionary just has 'color' added as a key. Why is that? Should they not all have 'device' as keys?

Comment: Yeah it happened by mistake, I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only print the resulting dictionaries, uncomment the print statement (and comment the following 2).

```
d1 = [
    {'index':'1','color':'red'},
    {'index':'2','color':'blue'},
    {'index':'3','color':'green'}
]

d2 = [
    {'device':'1','name':'x'},
    {'device':'2','name':'y'},
    {'device':'3','name':'z'}
]


result_list = []
for dict1 in d1:
    merged_dict = dict1.copy()
    for dict2 in d2:
        merged_dict.update(dict2)
#       print(merged_dict)
        result_list.append(merged_dict.copy())

print(result_list)
```

The result:

> [{'name': 'x', 'device': '1', 'color': 'red', 'index': '1'},
>   {'name': 'y', 'device': '2', 'color': 'red', 'index': '1'},
>   {'name': 'z', 'device': '3', 'color': 'red', 'index': '1'},
>   {'name': 'x', 'device': '1', 'color': 'blue', 'index': '2'},
>   {'name': 'y', 'device': '2', 'color': 'blue', 'index': '2'},
>   {'name': 'z', 'device': '3', 'color': 'blue', 'index': '2'},
>   {'name': 'x', 'device': '1', 'color': 'green', 'index': '3'},
>   {'name': 'y', 'device': '2', 'color': 'green', 'index': '3'},
>   {'name': 'z', 'device': '3', 'color': 'green', 'index': '3'}]

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to merge the n.-th dict of the first list with the n.-th dict of the second list you can do something like this:

```
a = [
    {'index':'1','color':'red'},
    {'index':'2','color':'blue'},
    {'index':'3','color':'green'}
]

b = [
    {'device':'1','name':'x'},
    {'device':'2','name':'y'},
    {'device':'3','name':'z'}
]

def merge(x,y):
    z = x.copy()
    z.update(y)
    return z

>>> [merge(x,y) for x,y in zip(a,b)]

[{'color': 'red', 'device': '1', 'index': '1', 'name': 'x'},
 {'color': 'blue', 'device': '2', 'index': '2', 'name': 'y'},
 {'color': 'green', 'device': '3', 'index': '3', 'name': 'z'}]
```

`merge(x,y)` is a helper function that returns a single dictionary with all contents of x and y.

`zip(a,b)` returns a list of tuples, where the first element of each tuple is an element of a and the second element is an element of b. This allows to use list comprehensions on two lists in parallel.

Comment: Why would you answer this? OP posted the exact same question 16 hours ago (which was answered). Answering obvious dupes only encourages this behavior.

Comment: it is not the same question actually, the output is different